# Canvas Element Squished in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, createjs

My canvas element distorts in Internet Explorer 9 & 10, it's at half of the height it should be.
The canvas should be a responsive 640x480 box with a large red circle, not an oblong ellipse. I'm hoping it would take a css spec fix, but I'm not clear what the css or javascript fix would be.

In ie10 and ie9 it looks like this:
http://s7.postimg.org/4xtb6vjkr/ie10.png

The code and correct display in chrome, firefox, safari and ie11 can be seen here:

http://jsbin.com/vutiqatowo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

This is a backwards compatibility requirement for a project, so wishing for visitors to not use ie10 is not an option for this.

Comment: The jsbin link should show the code, but here is the same set-up using fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=uzmExRky4H

Comment: replace height:auto; with height:100%;

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the *replace `height:auto` with `height:100%`* solution all over googled search results, but it is not working on the pages where it is an issue for me. 
I found this media query  hack for `-ms-high-contrast`, and that is working for the distorted canvas display. It's not providing a smooth scaling, but it will do for showing the canvas element correctly.

Here is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/trents_luck/abhbmsd6/

In the fiddle example, the media query hacks can be seen at the bottom of the css, they read something like this:

```
 @media (-ms-high-contrast: active) and (min-width: 100px), 
        (-ms-high-contrast: none) and (min-width: 100px)
```